# How to pass a user's screen name to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I want to display the user's screen name in a partial view that is contained in a master page. It is the classic "Log In" / "Welcome John Smith! Log Out" scenario. The user's screen name is different to the `User.Identity.Name` and requires a database look up, i.e.

```
AppUser currentUser = appRepository.GetAppUser(User.Identity.Name);
string screenName = currentUser.ScreenName;
```

This is not going to work from within a view - there is no reference to 'appRepository' and views shouldn't really be going around making database calls anyway. How should I set this up so that the screen name is passed to the view from the controller?

All my controllers inherit from a `BaseController`. I tried setting `ViewData["CurrentAppUser.ScreenName"]` in the constructor of the of the `BaseController` class, but at that point the User object is not populated yet. (I am using OpenID with DotNetOpenAuth if that is relevant.) I could set it in every action method on every controller, but that would be supremely ugly.

I also tried setting a session variable when the user logs on, but it seems a user can stay logged in even if the session ends. When they come back again they are still logged in, but the session variable is unset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you using [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). So as always you start by defining a view model:

```
public class UserInfoViewModel
{
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class UserInfoController: Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersRepository _repository;
    public UserInfoController(IUsersRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // Use this attribute if you want to restrict direct access
    // to this action.
    [ChilActionOnly] 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _repository.GetUserInfo(User.Identity.Name);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

a corresponding partial view:

```
@model UserInfoViewModel
<div>Hello @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ScreenName )</div>
```

finally in your master page (no matter which controller was used to render the view) include the partial:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "UserInfo")
```

or (`Html.RenderPartial` which does the same but doesn't return the result but writes it directly to the output stream):

```
@{Html.ActionPartial("Index", "UserInfo");}
```

A further improvement of this in order to avoid hitting the database on each request for fetching the user screen name would be to cache it somewhere: session, cookie, ...

So no need of base controllers and `ViewData`. The logic of getting the user screen name is completely separate from the main MVC pipeline and embedded as a widget.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant - thank you very much. Also thanks for the Haack link.